# Google Glass - Pan and Zoom Images using OpenCv

Tags: android, opencv, google-glass

I try to implement pan and zoom on Google Glass for taken pictures (using openCv).

My problem is to find "a good" possibility to pan once I zoomed in. Let's say I've zoomed in - I can now use a GestureDetector and use the onScroll method to move left and right, however, how about moving up and down? For sure, I can use the GestureDetector to detect motions like

```
 if (gesture == Gesture.TWO_SWIPE_RIGHT) {
   // do something
 }
```

to move down or up, but I loose the possibilty to get displacement, delta and velocity (parameters of onScroll) I had with the onScroll method and therefore offer an smooth pan functionality.

Any ideas how user experience can be improved on this?

Comment: Don't use the GestureDetector, but the regular MotionEvents reported by the onTouch() method.